# Redshift Super Data type Querying

Tags: amazon-redshift, partiql

Redshift's new super data type uses partiql for querying. I have an array of data that is not nested eg: `[0,1,2,3,4]`
What is the best way to query this data? All the documentation talks about nested arrays, but this is at the root level and there is no testing.

I have tried `select supercolumnname[n] from tablewithsuper;` and I am getting nulls, which isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

The best way (that I know right now) is to [unnest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html) the array:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_table (my_array SUPER);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (JSON_PARSE('[10001,10002,3333]'));
SELECT m FROM my_table as t, t.my_array as m;
```